# Toggle visibility of a boundfield on CheckedChanged event

Tags: asp.net, events, checkbox, visibility

I have a gridview with a couple of `BoundFields` in. What I wish to do is once I check (or un-check) a specific checkbox `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowExtra" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chkShowExtra_CheckedChanged" Text="Show extra details" Checked="False" />` it should toggle the visibility of several `BoundFields`. **How can I achieve this?**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CUS_DatabaseEdition" DataFormatString="" HeaderText="Edition" SortExpression="CUS_DatabaseEdition" Visible="false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Offices" HeaderText="O" SortExpression="Offices" Visible="false">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />              
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CUS_CustomerQuantity" HeaderText="Q" SortExpression="CUS_CustomerQuantity" Visible="false">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />              
</asp:BoundField>
```

I've also found this event which I think will come in handy.

```
protected void chkShowExtra_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to toggle the visibility of the `BoundFields`;

```
grdCategories.Columns[1].Visible = chkShowExtra.Checked;
grdCategories.Columns[2].Visible = chkShowExtra.Checked;
grdCategories.Columns[11].Visible = chkShowExtra.Checked;
```

Inside the `chkShowExtra_CheckedChanged` event.